# CakePHP search plugin

Tags: cakephp

I am looking for search plugin for cakephp, Unlike yii provides search by default, Is there any open source plugin we can have in cakephp. I have seen search plugin from CakeDC but its not free.

Answer (score 2):

What is "not free" with the [MIT license](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php)? Did you read the readme.md and docblocks?

MIT grants you more or less to do anything what you want with the code. You are just **not** allowed to remove the copyright of the original author of the code.

But we would appreciate a donation to the Cake Software Foundation. See http://cakephp.org/, right side "Donate".

Comment: I guess free isn't free enough anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about free (certainly seems like the CakeDC plugin is free), but if you are looking for a simple to use Filter plugin, I've been using this:

- http://lecterror.com/articles/view/cakephp-generic-filter-plugin
- https://github.com/lecterror/cakephp-filter-plugin

Its GPL/LGPL and I find it really easy to use with very little extra configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out this [plugin](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/search). It can be tricky to use, but once you get the hang of it, its a really nice plugin